# How to get Wix Burn bundle to block upgrade

Tags: wix, upgrade, burn

I have an series of beta versions of a product released that users must remove before installing the 'final public release'.

In this situation I would normally perform a major upgrade, but in this case the major upgrade is too difficult to implement because of the nature of the product. It would be much easier for future upgrades to start from a 'clean baseline'.

Is there a built-in way to get burn to detect and notify the user that previously installed version must be uninstalled?

Or do I need to add a package to the bundle that does the check, displays a message and makes the bundle fail?

If it's relevant to the answer, all previous releases have the same major.minor.patch version.  Just the build number changed e.g. 1.0.0.1, 1.0.0.20, 1.0.0.50; The final release is 1.0.0.100.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Upgrade table in your product's MSI is built as per "normal" usage, you can use the OnDetectRelatedMsiPackage callback into your BA to evaluate each installation found. You'll need to call MsiGetProductInfo() API (or the DTF equivalent?) within that callback to get the version string, then parse the string to determine if the installed version number is small enough to block/fail your installation.

Note that the Major Upgrade machinery in Windows Installer only checks the first three parts of the version quad, so Windows Installer itself cannot distinguish between 1.0.0.1 and 1.0.0.100. You may have an issue to contend with there.